# Building a "flat" API in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

When building an API in Loopback, I want to have relatively flat, authentication protected routes like: `/users`, `/orders`, etc. So, if I'm a user and I have some orders, I should be able to simply call `/orders` or `/orders/:id` to get one or more of the orders for my account.

Using Loopback's model relationships, I could do something like: `/users/:userId/orders` relatively easily, but there are definitely cases where I don't want to add in that complexity to the URL structure.

Is there a good, recommended way to do something like this? Seems like there should be a way to set this up such that the current user's access token tells Loopback which records it has access to and then can return only those.

Comment: thats a very good question. I think integrating this in the loopback will remove the API complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem wasn't terribly obvious, but I came up with something that works well enough, though it's a bit "manual."

First, in my case, I always have access to the user via `req.user`, which is a fairly common Node.js / Express pattern. I believe libs like Passport follow this as well.

Then, I created a generic helper method called that looks like this:

```
module.exports.sourceUser = function(ctx) {
  var req = ctx.req;

    if (!req.user) {
        var err = new Error('You must pass valid credentials to call this API.');
        err.statusCode = 401;
        throw err;
    }

    return req.user;
};
```

This will ensure that APIs I attach this method to will require user authentication, rejecting any request that doesn't have a valid user cred.

Next, since I'm defining flat APIs, I'm just defining my own remote methods (not using built-in Loopback ones). Each remote method def looks like this:

```
Model.remoteMethod('getRecord', {
    http: {
        verb: 'get',
        path: '/:id'
    },
    accepts: [
        { arg: 'id', type: 'string', required: true, http: { source: 'path' } },
        { arg: 'user', type: 'object', http: helpers.sourceUser }
    ],

    returns: [
        { arg: 'model', type: 'model', root: true }
    ]
});
```

You'll need to adjust that code to match your model names, etc. Also, notice the usage of `helpers.sourceUser` which is the thing that ensures we have a user and then provides that user as an argument to the API implementation.

Finally, I use a `where` clause in my database queries, etc to ensure that a user only gets/sets their own records (e.g. `where model.user == user.id`).

Hope this helps someone else...

Answer (score 1):

`/users/:userId/orders` is needed for admin area e.g
You should create a base route such `/me` for your situation.